I want to read binary values by fread and TCC does it well , also CLand GCC do it once in about 20 times but the rest are garbage values
I want to read files as binary and wrote this piece of code :
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    FILE * fp = fopen("/home/lovelorn/Pictures/post-3.jpeg", "rb");
    int n;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    fread(&n, 1, 1, fp);
    printf("%d\n ", n);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}

It's a JPEG file and must be 255 , 216 , 255 etc But GCC and CLang most of times in compiling , give me some random and garbage values and numbers and when I write fread(&n, 4, 1, fp) it become worse and negative numbers come up . What's wrong with this piece of code ? TCC always compile it true and give true numbers
As definition of fread is pointer for storing , I pass a variable by its address and I tried to redirect it but I couldn't and if this is wrong code ; How to read a file as numbers ( binary ) with fread . Thanks

fread is the wrong tool when n is int. Use char n;. Or, use int n; for (...) { n = fgetc(fp); ... Note that if you're getting negative numbers, in a binary file, it's possible to get sign extension. Try unsigned char n; And, for binary data, hex format is usually better: printf("%2.2X\n",n);

Your fread call is reading a single byte into n.  The remaining bytes could be anything.    In fact, the position of the non-garbage byte is architecture-dependent, and will vary depending on whether you're using a big- vs. little-endian machine.  If you want to read the values one byte at a time with fread, then pass a char *, not an int *.  But in that case, it would make more sense to call getc or fgetc.

@CraigEstey What is sign extension ? It works by unsigned char but with char it gives negative values and random numbers

sign extension means if char is a signed type then when converting to another signed type like int then the sign bits will be extended to keep the values intact. If you don't know basic things like bytes or signness then you should stop this and start reading a book first. Never learn by trial-and-error or by competitive programming sites. Printing bytes as decimal is usually a wrong way to do, you should print hex instead

@CraigEstey I got it , I've found it on wikipedia and understand the procedure . Thank You ........

@CraigEstey I read Your comment right not and didn't see that You wrote for Me ...... I'm self learning ; I had some books but none of them were clear and complete . I thought extension is something in Unix or GCC ..... I know how data types convert to each other .... But , Again Thank You ........
